# How to round a number with 10 decimals to just 3 decimals after the comma

Tags: php, mysql

I extract an average from several table fields with the same characteristics, and I use the following code:

here is my code

```
 <? $query = 'SELECT AVG(points) FROM table1 WHERE id_user = '.$id_user.'';
    $avg = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($avg);?>

<b><?= $row['AVG(answer)']?></b>
```

The thing is that sometimes this result is something like 8,1231452543635674563.
My question is how can I make it to show only first 3 digits after the comma (ex: 8,123)? Thank you!

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/round http://php.net/number_format http://php.net/sprintf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/number_format)

```
echo number_format($row['AVG(answer)'],3);
```

Also: you generally want to avoid short php tags like `<?=`. They make your code less portable, as many hosts don't have those enabled.

Comment: Avoiding `<?=` is slowly becoming less of an issue as that's enabled as a shortcut for `<?php echo` by default as of PHP 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Using just mysql, you could just use the [**FORMAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function:

```
<? $query = 'SELECT FORMAT(AVG(points),3) fmtavg FROM table1 WHERE id_user = '.$id_user.'';
   $avg = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($avg);?>

<b><?= $row['fmtavg']?></b>
```